# Menu navigaton responsive (no Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make this menu responsive, in particular I want it to appear like this : ☰  --> and when I click on it shows the links.

(The blue button, also I want it to appear as a normal link, like the other links)

I don't want to use Bootstrap, I want to use JavaScript And CSS.

HTML  CODE :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>  
<div class="navigation-main">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/logo-main.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" />Home</a>
        <a href="#" />Home</a>
        <a href="#" />Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu2">
        <a href="#" class=
        "button button-prim button-round button-small" />Button</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS CODE :

```
 * {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 }
body a, body a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation-main {
background-color: #1f2124;
height : 59px;
border-bottom : 0px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
width : 100%;
padding-top : 0px;
padding-bottom : 0px;
}
.logo {
width : 125px;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.logo img {
width : 38px;
height : 38px;
}
#menu a {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 19px;
padding-bottom: 22px;
position: relative;
left: 70px;
bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu2 a {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 19px;
padding-bottom: 22px;
position: relative;
left: 1200px;
bottom: 50px;
}
.menu2 {
float: right;
}
#menu a:hover {
background-color: #2c97de;
}
.button-small {
height: 35px;
line-height: 31px;
font-size: 13px;
}
.button-round {
border-radius: 38px;
}
.button-prim {
background-color: #2c97de;
}
.button {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 38px;
color: #fff;
outline: none;
border: 2px solid transparent;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
bottom: 48px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for our project.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/Hg4Ts/4/)

### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function CloseNav() {
        $(".navbar-collapse").stop().animate({'height': 0},300, function () {
            $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in').addClass("collapse");
        });
        $(".navbar-toggle").stop().removeClass('collapsed');
    }

    $('html').click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
            CloseNav();
        }

    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.wrapper {width:100%, height:100%;}
```

GL :-)